# Change class when click image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the class content when i click the image.

```
<div class="myclass">
Content
</div>
<div class="myclass">
Content
</div>
<div class="myclass">
Content
</div>

<ul>
  <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="image5.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Here i want to go to the 1 st content if i click the 1st image and increment like that. Is this possible ?

Comment: class of all Divs with myClass ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img', 'ul').on('click', function() {
    $(".myclass").eq($(this).parent('li').index()).show()
                 .siblings('div').hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9URHw/1/)

Comment: Hey can u solve this please ? http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/namVk/1/  If i click the second image then i click next, it doesn't update. Please help me.